# Android streaming video latency

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, video-streaming, latency

I am trying to run Example One from https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming-examples
It uses libstreaming-4.0.
I have forced it to use encodeWithMediaCodecMethod2(). This method uses the createInputSurface() method introduced in Android 4.3. This reduced the latency from 3 seconds to 1 second.
I am creating a video chat application (like Skype) and I need the video latency to be much lower than this.
I don't know where to go from here really.
Could anyone offer suggestions on how to get the latency down? Different libraries? techniques? maybe the NDK?  I have done loads of research but I have had very little luck :(
Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thre are few open source projects

1. [doubango](https://code.google.com/p/doubango/)
2. [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) (you will need [javacv](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv) - Java wrapper for C/C++ SDK)

Also thre is [IMSDroid](https://code.google.com/p/imsdroid/) (open source 3GPP IMS Client for Android based on doubango) and FFMpeg's streaming [guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide#Latency) about latency